# Unable to print PDF with Staple mode in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I am using PrintTicket object (printTicket.Stapling = Stapling.StapleTopLeft;) and using PrintQueue.Addjob method in System.printing to enable stapling option. Stapling is working fine with XPS document, but not working with PDF documents. Here is my code:

```
PrintTicket printTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;                        
printTicket.Stapling = Stapling.StapleTopLeft;
printQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket = printTicket;
printQueue.AddJob("TEST", "C:\\TEST.XPS", false, printTicket);
```

TEST.XPS is printing and stapling, but changing the file to PDF is not working.

Comment: Your printer physically staples pages together?

Comment: Yes it does staples pages together.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the MDSN for that AddJob method it specifically says it for XPS documents only.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205516%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Inserts a new print job for an XML Paper Specification (XPS) Document
>   into the queue, gives it the specified name and settings, and
>   specifies whether or not it should be validated.

Comment: Thanks @CathalMF. Any idea I can use this PrintTicket settings to print documents in other format?

Comment: @Gaurav I dont know. I dont actually have a printer so i cant test it.